# Trying to calculate suicides per decade in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started with Python and I am trying to analyze some data, the current goal is a graph with Y being total amout and X being the year.

I've tried finding people with similar issues but to no real succsess. I've tried reading up on arrays and even tried my hand at 2D arrays but with no succsess either.

```
for row in csv.reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Comumn names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        elif line_count <= 1000:
            print(f"\t{row[0]} is the country and {row[1]} the year. The 
                     sex was {row[2]}.")
            t = f"\t{row[0]} is the country and {row[1]} the year. The 
                     sex was {row[2]}."

            if " male" in t:
                males += 1
            elif "female" in t:
                females += 1
            else:
                none += 1
            line_count += 1
        else:
           break



def stat():
       if "198" in line_count(row[1]):
           total[0] += 1
       elif "199" in line_count(row[1]):
            total[1] += 1
       elif "200" in line_count(row[1]):
            total[2] += 1
       elif "201" in line_count(row[1]):
            total[3] += 1
       elif "202" in line_count(row[1]):
            total[4] += 1
```

The issue is with my matplotlib is using the plt.plot()

I'm trying to do do something around the lines of:

```
plt.plot(years, currentDecadenDeaths)



years = [1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020]

currentDecadenDeaths = [[years[0],[years[1],[years[2],[years[3], 
[years[4], [total[0], total[1], total[2], total[3], total[4]]]

plt.plot(years, currentDecadenDeaths)
```

Comment: whats your error?

Comment: plt .plot requires 2 list of same size.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

```
years = [1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020]

currentDecadenDeaths = [total[0], total[1], total[2], total[3], total[4]]

plt.plot(years, currentDecadenDeaths)
```

Comment: This fixed my syntax error but now gave me an error in my function stat(), It now can't seem to find my row[1] in : if "198" in line_count(row[1]):

Comment: you have not given full code so don't mention line 198.